# ReferenceError: require is not defined with Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, require

I am working on a backend app.js with node. I have node installed, installed express, but I keep getting this ReferenceError with I do npm start. This is my current app.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
```

I have tried almost everything I've found on Google. I changed it to:

`import * as express from "express";`

but that only gave me:

`TypeError: express is not a function`

I also have a frontend react app. I'm not sure if that helps. Sorry if my explanation doesn't make sense. I'm just trying to figure out if my code is bad or it's something else.

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file?

Comment: If your main file is configured to be an ESM module (instead of the original CommonJS module), then there is no `require()` in an ESM module.  You would use `import` instead.  If `import express from 'express';` isn't working, then make sure you have properly installed express.

Answer (score 1):

would you mind sharing your **package.json** or do you have your code in some playground app like **codepen** or **fiddle**?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your package.json file to see what does is script written for "start"

Does it say something like `"start": "node app.js"`? Try running `node app.js` instead of `npm start`

Comment: I've tried both. My package.json has "start" so everything is as usual there as well. It seems like the main issue is not understanding what 'require' is even though node is installed

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 5000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send({hi: 'there'})
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```